# How to fix No env file present for the current environment?

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, dotenv

**.env.development**

```
secret_key=abcd
```

**.env.production**

```
secret_key=abcde
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development & node server.js",
"prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production & node server.js",
"lint": "eslint",
"start": "node server.js"
```

},

**in main file**

```
require('custom-env').env(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

**But when i try**

```
npm run dev or npm run prod
```

*It shows No env file present for the current environment:production/development*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here if you want to get a particular environment.

Create a `.env.development` file in your app's root directory

```
require('custom-env').env('development')
```

Inside `package.json` should be like this.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development&& node server.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In package.json I just Changed**

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development&& node server.js",
  "prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production&& node server.js",
  "lint": "eslint",
  "start": "node server.js"
  }
```

**and it worked.**

Answer (score 0):

Got this message even if .env.development existed. There must NOT be space after "development":

Correct:

```
set NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon --exec babel-node ./bin/www
```

Wrong:

```
set NODE_ENV=development && nodemon --exec babel-node ./bin/www
```